# Dynamically added content issue in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

My question is general in nature. I have seen that, if i add a dynamic element, i can use jQuery on function to register the click (and other events). Lets say i am using a jQuery plugin, that acts by associating a class to the div. If the div is dynamically created, and the plugin is not using .on then the click function might not work. In such cases, is there anyway to solve these dynamically created div issues like reregistering the divs or something else ?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery plugins usually do not use event delegation for their handlers. When you add elements dynamically, you usually need to call the plugin's initialization function explicitly on the new elements. For instance, if you're using Datepicker, and you add a new date field to your form, it should be something like:

```
$("<input type='text' ...>").appendTo("#formID").datepicker({ ... });
```

Comment: i didnt understand the above line, basically because i have never used datepicker. But in general, how do we approach such issues ? can you refer me any document or resource that addresses this issue ?

Comment: It's essentially the same with any plugin. Whatever you normally do in `$(document).ready()` to initialize it on static elements, you have to do again on the newly-added elements.